# How to send address from geocoder class to another activity?

Tags: java, android, dictionary, android-activity, reverse-geocoding

I have this particular ChooseFromMapActivity in my app. In this the address is taken by using reverse geocoding so as we move the map the location is changed on the TextView below use location layout. 
Like below:

[image]

Now I want to show this particular current location on the edit text view of another activity. Like below :

[image]

In this, In the geocoder class location is stored in StringBuilder str variable. So I tried to retrieve string from str and show it on the text view. But Its not the perfect address as shown in the text view. str variable just shows the local area and postal code. I want to show perfect geo coded value in the edit text view. So is it correct way to use StringBuilder variable?? or Is there any other way to achieve it??

In this the latitude and longitude is stored in center  variable this center variable is latlng variable. Can we pass latlng variable to another activity?? And how can we show the latlng variables address in edit text view??
Please help me out..

ChooseFromMapActivity

```
   public class ChooseFromMapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
GoogleMap mGoogleMap;

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
boolean mUpdatesRequested = false;
private LatLng center;
private LinearLayout markerLayout;
private Geocoder geocoder;
private List<Address> addresses;
private TextView Address;
double latitude;
double longitude;
private GPSTracker gps;
private LatLng curentpoint;
private LinearLayout useLocation;
Intent intent;
double x, y;
StringBuilder str;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_from_map);
    Address = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textShowAddress);
    markerLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.locationMarker);
    useLocation = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearUseLoc);

    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

    if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) { // Google Play Services are
        // not available

        int requestCode = 10;
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this,
                requestCode);
        dialog.show();

    } else { // Google Play Services are available

        // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment
        // Create a new global location parameters object
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();

        /*
         * Set the update interval
         */
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(GData.UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

        // Use high accuracy
        mLocationRequest
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        // Set the interval ceiling to one minute
        mLocationRequest
                .setFastestInterval(GData.FAST_INTERVAL_CEILING_IN_MILLISECONDS);

        // Note that location updates are off until the user turns them on
        mUpdatesRequested = false;

        /*
         * Create a new location client, using the enclosing class to handle
         * callbacks.
         */
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    useLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


           /* Intent intent = new Intent(ChooseFromMapActivity.this ,GoSend.class);
           intent.putExtra("latitude",latitude);
            intent.putExtra("Longitude",longitude);
            startActivity(intent);*/
        ///    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
          //  bundle.putSerializable("value",str);
          //  intent.putExtras(bundle);

            intent = new Intent(ChooseFromMapActivity.this,GoSend.class);
            String value=str.toString();
           // intent.putExtra("value",value);
            intent.putExtra("x",x);
            intent.putExtra("y",y);
            startActivity(intent);

         //   intent.putExtra("string", (Serializable) str);

          //  Bundle args = new Bundle();
            //args.putParcelable("from_position",curentpoint);
          //  intent.putExtra("bundle", args);
            //Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        }
    });
}


private void stupMap() {
    try {

        mGoogleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();

        // Enabling MyLocation in Google Map
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
        mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);

        gps = new GPSTracker(this);

        gps.canGetLocation();

        latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        longitude = gps.getLongitude();
        curentpoint = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(curentpoint).zoom(19f).tilt(70).build();

        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        // Clears all the existing markers
        mGoogleMap.clear();

        mGoogleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                center = mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().target;

                mGoogleMap.clear();
                markerLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                try {
                    new GetLocationAsync(center.latitude, center.longitude)
                            .execute();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        });


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    stupMap();

}

private class GetLocationAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    // boolean duplicateResponse;


    public GetLocationAsync(double latitude, double longitude) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        x = latitude;
        y = longitude;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            geocoder = new Geocoder(ChooseFromMapActivity.this, Locale.ENGLISH);
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(x, y, 1);
            str = new StringBuilder();
            if (Geocoder.isPresent()) {

                if ((addresses != null) && (addresses.size() > 0)) {
                    Address returnAddress = addresses.get(0);

                    String localityString = returnAddress.getLocality();
                    String city = returnAddress.getCountryName();
                    String region_code = returnAddress.getCountryCode();
                    String zipcode = returnAddress.getPostalCode();

                    str.append(localityString + "");
                    str.append(city + "" + region_code + "");
                    str.append(zipcode + "");



                }
            } else {
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {
            Address.setText(addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0)
                    + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1) + " ");


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
      }
```

GoSend

```
public class GoSend extends AppCompatActivity {
LatLng latLng;
private GoogleMap mMap;
MarkerOptions markerOptions;
LinearLayout ll;
Toolbar toolbar;
EditText editTextLocation;
EditText edtxt_from;
EditText edtxt_to;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gosendlayout);

    Location l=new Location();
    setUI();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
    }



    Intent intent = this.getIntent();
    String data = intent.getStringExtra("x");
    String d=intent.getStringExtra("y");
    String data1=(data+d);
    edtxt_from.setText(data1);


    //Bundle bundle = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("bundle");
 //  double fromPosition = bundle.getParcelable("from_position");

  //  edtxt_from.setText(fromPosition);
   /* Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
   if (extras != null) {
        double latitude = extras.getDouble("latitude");
       double longitude = extras.getDouble("Longitude");


        edtxt_from.setText(String.valueOf(latitude));*/


 //   Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

//    Serializable value =bundle.getSerializable("value");

     //   edtxt_from.setText(String.valueOf(longitude));
    }



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void setUI() {

    ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayoutGoSend);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("GO-SEND");



    try {
        if (mMap == null) {
            mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().
                    findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        }
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

     edtxt_from=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_from);
     edtxt_to=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_to);

    edtxt_from.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),PickLocationActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    edtxt_to.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent  i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),PickLocationActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

}
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass address as a string from one activity to another by setting that address in the intent you are using to start the other activity like

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ChooseFromMapActivity.this, GoSend.class); 
intent.putExtra("addressTag", stringAddress);
startActivity(intent);
```

and on the other hand in the receiving activity you can can get it like this

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if(bundle != null)
    String stringAddress = bundle.getString("addressTag");
```

Comment: I have done this for my SringBuilder variable.. My coe is this :       intent = new Intent(ChooseFromMapActivity.this,GoSend.class);
                String value=str.toString();
               intent.putExtra("value",value);                                                                                    On another activity:   
        Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        String data = intent.getStringExtra("value");
        edtxt_from.setText(data);
                startActivity(intent);

Comment: if it is not working replace it with the code i have provided and update me

Comment: I am getting address like MiraBhyndarIndialNull.. and its showing in text view as c-47,swaminarayan rdSector 3, Mira road east @ Zubair Akber

Comment: make sure that you are passing the same vale as you are setting to your textView

Comment: I am not sure about which value is going to text view.. Can you please look at the code and let me know the value?? @ Zubair Akber

Comment: i think so it is using Address.setText(addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0)
                    + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1) + " ");

Comment: Thank you.. ya so how to send this to another activity?? @Zubair Akber

Comment: Address is a text view variable. Can we pass it to another activity?? and how to set this to edit text view?

Comment: addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0) + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1) + " " pass this

Comment: got it...Thank you so much...@Zubair Akber

Comment: your welcome ... accept and rate my answer when ever you will be eligible to do ...

Answer (score 0):

Simpler way is to create a model class called Address.

```
class Address implements Serializable{

String Street;

String City;
//...Fileds

}
```

Fill information in this class and send it as Serializable object in intent.